# TFS / Visual Studio Team Services Iterations with overlapping dates

Tags: tfs, scrum, azure-devops

I am trying to implement a single Team Project with multiple sub-projects as recommended by [this guy](http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/09/05/153944.aspx) and [this guy](http://nakedalm.com/one-team-project/). But I have hit a snag. VS Team Services does not allow iterations to have overlapping start and completion dates. Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterations are a hierarchy. Within a single team you wouldn't have overlapping iteration dates, but if you have multiple teams within a team project you can model it as a hierarchy of iterations.  Something like so:

```
Team A 
  Sprint 1 
  Sprint 2 
  Sprint 3 
Team B 
  Sprint 1 
  Sprint 2 
  Sprint 3
```

Then in the team settings you just have to make sure to only associate each team to the iterations for that team.  So long as no iterations assigned to a specific team overlap you should be OK.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That works fine. The top level iteration is not an iteration but a Team or a Project.

Comment: Just to note, iterations are hierarchical, so the top level could indeed be an iteration albeit one without dates.

Comment: Thank you @Dylan-Smith (and Andrew) I have asked a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009758/prevent-all-users-being-able-to-see-all-users-teams-groups-and-iterations-in-t) and would be very grateful for your input.